# Fluid background centred fixed content

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with the most efficient and correct way of doing this. Much like the design on stack overflow. I want a header where the background colour of the header extends across the whole page, but the content of the header and the content of the main body is centred and fixed.

This is the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/kYfNB/13/

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Admin</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="jobs.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="sites.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="feeds.html">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
         <h1>Add</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#header {
    background-color:#1ABC9C;
    overflow:auto;
}
#header a {
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background-color: #16AD8F;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
#header a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
#header h1, #header ul, #header ul li {
    float:left;
}
#content {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
#container {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kYfNB/15/?

Comment: Not really since the content isn't centred within the page and the background doesn't extend all the way across. The stack overflow header is a good example, where the black bar extends all the way across but the header content is fixed in the middle of the page

Comment: Well you set a width on #container, `width: 600px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `margin: 0 auto;` to an element it will sit in the center of a parent element, that can stretch across the whole page.
You would need to split the header part form the content part. And use separate container elements (i called them `.inner` in my example) that are centered and have the desired width.
You would put the once that stretch across the page around the inner ones ( here I used your `#container` element) and apply the bgcolor.

Something like this:

CSS

```
...
.inner {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#1ABC9C;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header" class="inner">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Admin</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="jobs.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="sites.html">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="feeds.html">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="inner">
     <h1>Add</h1>
</div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/kYfNB/19/)

Comment: That is exactly the result, thank you. Is it necessary to have all that markup for example do we still need the container tag?

Comment: OK, I cleaned the markup up a little ... now there is not more than you had before ... just the content that is stretching across the screen and green is only around the header part. the class `.inner` sets the width and the centering for the contained elements. Is this acceptable now? ;-)